# insert/update/delete image from sql data with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert/delete,update image in sql database using asp.net. My code of inserting is:

```
    Stream strm = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(strm);
        byte[] img = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(strm.Length)); 
        imgDetail.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(img, 0, img.Length);
        imgDetail.Visible = true;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Persons (id,Name,Surname,Address,Phone,Picture,Department) values (@id,@Name,@Surname,@Address,@Phone,@img,@Department)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txtId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", txtSurname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("img", img);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", Department.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

I think something went wrong with added image, maybe i do this wrong .Now when i click on some record in my gridview, all data of the record displays in the textboxes, but i cant do display image in imagebox. how can i do this?
this is part of displaing data in textboxes:

```
     foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                GridViewRow row1 = GridView1.SelectedRow;
                txtId.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
                txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                txtSurname.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                txtAddress.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
                txtPhone.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
                Department.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
                Image.??????
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Image" control is a just a wrapper around the standard `<img>` HTML-tag. So obviously it does not have any binary property, that you can set to a byte-array.

But you go with a "data" uri.

Here's an idea for you:

```
Image.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])imagedata);
```